How to set up Poetry/Conda virtual environment with AWS Neuron
Has anyone been able to set up a Poetry or Conda virtual environment on a AWS Trainium instance? I've been trying to do this following the Neuron installation instructions for Ubuntu 22 and PyTorch 2.1.2, but I keep running into no-compatible-version errors before I can get neuronx-cc, torch-neuron, and torchvision all installed.
I guess all that I need is a working project.toml file or the conda equivalent.
